# Why Edge browser trims images?

Tags: css, svg, microsoft-edge

I have some .svg files. They display correctly in Chrome, Firefox, this way:
[image]
But in Edge they are trimmed:
[image]

I tried everything, but with no result. Only super big sizes seems to display right. So should I set it size, for example, 100px x 100px, and then scale it? It will be inaccurate...

```css
.button-wrapper {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20.313' height='20.313' viewBox='0 0 20.313 20.313'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.978 2.978A9.783 9.783 0 0110.156 0a9.783 9.783 0 017.178 2.979 9.783 9.783 0 012.979 7.178 9.783 9.783 0 01-2.979 7.174 9.783 9.783 0 01-7.178 2.981 9.783 9.783 0 01-7.178-2.981A9.783 9.783 0 010 10.156a9.783 9.783 0 012.978-7.178zm13.257 1.1a8.282 8.282 0 00-6.079-2.516 8.282 8.282 0 00-6.079 2.515 8.282 8.282 0 00-2.515 6.079 8.282 8.282 0 002.515 6.075 8.282 8.282 0 006.079 2.519 8.282 8.282 0 006.079-2.519 8.282 8.282 0 002.515-6.079 8.282 8.282 0 00-2.515-6.075zm-7.446.806l4.687 4.686.488.586-.488.586-4.687 4.689-1.172-1.173 4.15-4.1-4.15-4.1z' fill='%232699fb'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <a href="/" class="button">d</a>
</div>
```

SVG

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20.313" height="20.313" viewBox="0 0 20.313 20.313"><defs><style>.a{fill:#2699fb;}</style></defs><path class="a" d="M5.322-16.553A9.783,9.783,0,0,1,12.5-19.531a9.783,9.783,0,0,1,7.178,2.979,9.783,9.783,0,0,1,2.979,7.178A9.783,9.783,0,0,1,19.678-2.2,9.783,9.783,0,0,1,12.5.781,9.783,9.783,0,0,1,5.322-2.2,9.783,9.783,0,0,1,2.344-9.375,9.783,9.783,0,0,1,5.322-16.553Zm13.257,1.1A8.282,8.282,0,0,0,12.5-17.969a8.282,8.282,0,0,0-6.079,2.515A8.282,8.282,0,0,0,3.906-9.375,8.282,8.282,0,0,0,6.421-3.3,8.282,8.282,0,0,0,12.5-.781,8.282,8.282,0,0,0,18.579-3.3a8.282,8.282,0,0,0,2.515-6.079A8.282,8.282,0,0,0,18.579-15.454Zm-7.446.806L15.82-9.961l.488.586-.488.586L11.133-4.1,9.961-5.273l4.15-4.1-4.15-4.1Z" transform="translate(-2.344 19.531)"/></svg>
```

---

[EDIT]

**SOLUTION**:

I edited SVG file: change `width="20.313" height="20.313" viewBox="0 0 20.313 20.313"` to `width="22" height="22" viewBox="-2 -2 24 24"`.

Comment: We'd need to see the mark up of button-arrow.svg please edit the question to include it.

Comment: I would try with `background-size: contain;`. Also is this links to pages or actions with some script event to them?

Comment: @Dejan.S I tried with background-size, it didn't help. Links are links to pages, without any other actions.

Comment: I can't re-create this in edge for mac. Do you have any display flex on the parent element?

Comment: Can't recreate this in Edge for Win10 latest either. Do you possibly have some sort of scaling or zooming or something enabled just on that browser? I ask because your second image appears a bit blurry, also not sure what the point of the huge negative text-indent is for but that's probably not relevant here.

Comment: Now I see that I have also position: absolute on .button-wrapper, and it causes trimming... Sorry, I didn't notice that.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using your code. It looks the same in Chrome and Microsoft Edge. The result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7makt.png) in both browsers. From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue, you could put the solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Basically I don't have an answer, I only know that problem disappear when I remove `position: absolute`. But I need `position: absolute`... Even in IE 11 it displays good, only in Edge is the problem. Strange...

Comment: Ok, I have solution, I edited my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: I edited SVG file: change width="20.313" height="20.313" viewBox="0 0 20.313 20.313" to width="22" height="22" viewBox="-2 -2 24 24".